# block of javascript won't run

Tags: javascript, firebug

take a look at this:
[image: firebug screen]
this is a screen I took from firebug. I don't know why but the browser just refuse to run the code within the lines with gray line number.The breakpoint above is never reached. There is no  syntax error, no warning whatsoever. What have I ran into?

edit: I tried with latest chrome and firefox.

Comment: u need a firebug for ur firebug

Comment: It should not be executed unless you don't call it

Comment: what do you mean I don't call it? the code with green line number executed fine.

Comment: If `this.running` isn't true, how will it ever execute the code at all?

Comment: I assume that `console.log()` doesn't show anything either? What about other browsers?

Comment: 'this' refers to a node. So 'this.running' not true means this node isn't running yet, not the program. The program itself should still execute like normal. Still I 'll try to remove that bit of code, see if it would run.

Comment: oddly console.log() does show, but the code still can't be step to. But pass that point console.log won't show either.

Comment: add a new(different, simple) statement after console.log and try to step to it

Comment: part of the code that I move to another function will run. Still the code after the first line of do while will not run no matter what. I assume this is a defect of do while?

Comment: Post a link or create a jsFiddle showing the behavior. Trying to debug a screenshot is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

I simply avoid do while at that place and it works! Never really sure why.